# Progress Bar not showing updated value when i am coming back from another controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, download, delegates, nsnotificationcenter

I want to show download progress in table view cell, but when i am coming back from another controller then progress bar not showing updated value in cell. It'll show only last received value. I tried to update progress value using NOTIFICATION CENTER and DELEGATE, but both are not working. How can I achieve this. Please help me.

Here is my code which i implemented in my project. 
startDownloading methods is implented in common class of my project

```
func startDownloading(url: String, indexpath: IndexPath) {
if (NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable) {

    let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)

    Alamofire.download(URL(string: url)!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil, to: destination).downloadProgress(queue: .main) { (progress) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("download: \(progress)")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("downloadSong"), object: ["row": indexpath.row, "value": progress])
        }
        }.response(queue: .global(qos: .background)) { (response) in
            if let destinationPath = response.destinationURL {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("downloadSong"), object: indexpath.row)
                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "downloadSong"), object: nil)
            }
    }
} else {
    print("Please connect to Internet.")
}
}
```

and following method implemented in UIViewcontroller class:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellReuseIdentifier") as! AllSongsTableCell
    cell.downloadTapped = {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateCell(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("downloadSong"), object: nil)
        startDownloading(url: "song-url", indexpath: indexPath)
    }
}

//Observer Method
@objc func updateCell(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let object = notification.object as? [String: Any] {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let cell = self.allSongsTable.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: object["row"] as! Int, section: 0)) as? AllSongsTableCell {
                let value = object["value"] as! Double
                cell.graphView.value = UICircularProgressRing.ProgressValue(value)
            }
            self.allSongsTable.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: object, section: 0)], with: .none)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Manisha, I suggest to store the progress (got from alamofire response) in a variable. So in your case if it is in tableView cell so you should keep the value in array variable to maintain the progress value of each rows downloading. then once you move between controllers, just need to refresh the `tableView` so it will load the array data (we stored from alamofire progress completion block)

Comment: Yes, here i am using object type array and storing progress value and it is showing stored value when i came back to View controller. But what will happen if download not completed for that particular cell and again i came to my controller(where file is still downloading in background). In that case my notification observer method is not updating cell progress value.

Comment: In that case, there are few important things need to be handled. First, store the progress in localstorage such as coredata or realm uniquely by its id or task id to keep the value always accessible. Second thing, you need to use queue for each download task so it always alive and can be check using task id. Also keep note when your apps going to background or terminated, handle the progress in appdelegate